# ggplot2::scale_fill_identity() is not applying fills as mapped in dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting data with ggplot in R and trying to map colors to fruits through a column in the dataframe. I expect `scale_fill_identity()` to map these fills to `geom_col()`, but it switches the colors of two fruits. Reproducible snippet below:

```
f <- tibble(
  fruit=factor(c('banana','apple','clementine'),c('clementine','banana','apple')),
  value=c(20, 30, 50),
  color=c('yellow','red','orange'),
)

# table is as-expected
# bananas are yellow, apples are red, clementines are orange
f

# factors ordered properly
f |> count(fruit)

# auto colors look fine
f |> ggplot(aes('x', value, fill=fruit)) + geom_col()

# bananas are red, apples are yellow
f |> ggplot(aes('x', value, fill=color)) + geom_col() +
  scale_fill_identity(guide='legend', labels=levels(f$fruit))

# why are colors not matching the mapping i have in the table?
# should i be using something like breaks=f$color in the identity call?
```

What am I missing, shouldn't I be able to use map colors like this? I know I can provide a named vector in `values` of `scale_fill_manual()`, but I'd rather add values to the dataframe. Also, should I be using the `breaks` argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your `breaks` of your "color" column and remove `levels` from your `labels` like this:

```r
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
f <- tibble(
  fruit=factor(c('banana','apple','clementine'),c('clementine','banana','apple')),
  value=c(20, 30, 50),
  color=c('yellow','red','orange'),
)

f |> ggplot(aes('x', value, fill=color)) + geom_col() +
  scale_fill_identity(guide='legend', labels=f$fruit, breaks = f$color)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Reverse order legend using `rev`:

```r
f |> ggplot(aes('x', value, fill=color)) + geom_col() +
  scale_fill_identity(guide='legend', labels=rev(f$fruit), breaks = rev(f$color))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Can you reverse the legend so it matches the charting order? Also, why does this not work if i exclude the legend altogether? Do the identity scales not work intelligently with factors?

Comment: Hi @Raesu, you could change the order in legend using `rev` (see update). It is possible with factors.